# How to make jQuery variable toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an app where you can customize the opacity of different elements. The app has simple "up" and "down" buttons, for increasing and decreasing opacity. However, the toggle functions are not implementing in my css. Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="container">Make me lighter.</div>
<br>
<br>
<button id="up">up</button>
<br>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

CSS:

```
* {
     margin: 0px;
     padding:0px
}

#container {
     padding: 10px;
     border: 10px solid;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 0.5;

    $("#up").click(function () {
        var x = x += 0.2;
    });
    $("#down").click(function () {
        var x = x -= 0.2;
    });

    $("#container").css({
        'opacity', x
    });
});
```

This is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j96bu778/1/

I've spent a lot of time looking up questions on Stack Overflow, and most of the answers were too confusing to understand. JQuery API didn't help me that much either.

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code (but don't be discouraged!):

1. `var x = x += 0.2;` is probably not the kind of assignment you're trying to do. This increments `x` by `0.2`, then assigns a new local variable `x` to the value of the evaluated `x`. Since x it accessible from the scope of the callback functions, just use `x += .2`.
2. `{ 'opacity', x }` in the `css` function argument is not valid object notation. You're looking for `{ opacity: x }`.
3. You need to set the CSS of the elements **when the buttons are pressed**. By omitting that from the event callbacks, your buttons don't do anything. I've moved `$("#container").css({opacity: x});` inside those callback functions.

Now fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 0.5;
    $("#up").click(function(){
        x += .2;
        $("#container").css({opacity: x});
     });
    $("#down").click(function(){
        x -= .2;
        $("#container").css({opacity: x});
     });
});
```

Check out a working demo here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j96bu778/7/)

I strongly recommend you do some reading on Javascript before diving into jQuery, as you'll have a much better understanding of how the language works.

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted, because it's the first answer to correctly explain all three problems.

Comment: Surely the inital `var x` should read the current opacity so it will progressively have higher opacity when clicked multiple times?

Comment: In my JSFiddle demo, I've set the initial opacity of `#container` to `0.5`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I have a better idea of what's going on here. Were the "var" 's in the original code creating new global variables each time? @analytalica

Comment: The `var x`'s I've removed from the original code were declaring variables in the scope of the callback functions. Those `x` vars are inaccessible outside.

Answer (score 1):

You never update the CSS in the click events, so it stays with the original value of `x`.

Also, you're not using closures right, since you're redeclaring and reinitializing `x` in each scope rather than allowing it to reference the variable in the parent scope.

Finally, you're using the wrong syntax for `css` calls (and object notation); just use the `'property', value` parameter notation without wrapping them.

Untested correction for all these problems:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 0.5;
    $("#up").click(function () {
        x = x += 0.2;
        $("#container").css('opacity', x);
    });
    $("#down").click(function () {
        x = x -= 0.2;
        $("#container").css('opacity', x);
    });

    $("#container").css('opacity', x);
});
```

Comment: that'st not the problem

Comment: @KevinSimple: Can you explain what is, or why this observation is incorrect, then?

Comment: I added $("#container").css({'opacity', x}); to both of my click events, but it still won't update the CSS.

Comment: @jaker: And once more with feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Find here **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j96bu778/5/)**.

Replace :

```
$("#up").click(function () {
     var x = x += 0.2;
});
```

By :

```
$("#up").click(function(){
    x += 0.2;    
    $("#container").css('opacity', x);
});
```

And same for **#down**, Because if `$("#container").css('opacity', x);` still outside of the click event, it was called just the first time on load of page.

**Full JS :**

```
$(function() {
    var x = 0.5;

    $("#up").click(function(){
        x += 0.2;    
        $("#container").css('opacity', x);
    });

    $("#down").click(function(){
        x -= 0.2;    
        $("#container").css('opacity', x);
     });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: I think that my syntax within the click handler was what I was missing. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

your jquery should like this...

since you set your var x as global variable, you don't need to declare it again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var x = 0.5;
        $("#up").click(function(){
           x += 0.2;
           $("#container").css('opacity', x);
         });
        $("#down").click(function(){
            x -= 0.2;
           $("#container").css('opacity', x);
         });

    });
```

Comment: This code is correct, but you're missing explanations for two of the three problems in the original.

Answer (score -1):

Mate, it's because you never change the css when click event occurs,

I updated your code, and it's working, check this

```
 $("#up").click(function(){
     x += 0.2;
     $("#container").css('opacity', x);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j96bu778/6/

Comment: well, sorry for that, I was just trying to help him sorting out the problem and you original answer was not quite right..

Comment: @KevinSimple: It's not the correction I mind, it's the lack of explanation that went along with it, several times over. Do please correct me, but if possible, in a way that is not simply a more verbose downvote.